# SQLite app works on emulator but not in phone seems database error

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an working on a SQLite app and I am new to Android. Everything works fine for me in emulator and when I install in phone unfortunately my app closes. I searched in StackOverflow and googled it, and I find some solutions but nothing worked. Finally I need some help.

My code to getdb from assets is:

```
private void copyDatabaseFromAssets() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        String DataBasePath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        try{

            inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
            outputStream =new FileOutputStream(DataBasePath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while((length =inputStream.read(buffer))>0){
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

        }catch(IOException e){
            throw new Error("Problem copying database from resource file");
        }

}
```

Comment: "unfortunately my app closes" -> where is your stack trace ?

Comment: most likely you have problem with permissions, copy your stack trace here and people can help you by that.
on top of my head, add this line in your manifest:
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: In Java stack trace console nothing is displayed.. And in Log cat other is no issues..

Comment: In error log is issue unhandled event loop exception and No command output when running looks like activity or intent issue..

Comment: You are swallowing all the information associated with the exception.

Comment: I am sorry to say that I am a very beginner and I don't know how to debug.But In my eclipse ADT I can able to see only log cat and error log issues In console only android is displaying other options are not printing any...

Comment: ok..show the error message..else you can`t get answer..

Comment: uninstall & re-install the application in your phone..

Comment: Your problem is the `try`/`catch`; remove it.

Comment: Why it is marked as duplicate ??I have tried that before asking but that post is not useful to me...

Comment: Finally I found the solution but I am unable to share the answers as it is marked duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that in your android manifest you have this permission

The problem could be that, if not, please show your logcat or stacktrace when error occurs.

Regards